# FileNotFoundError in ...\.cache\ using SentenceTransformer

Tags: python, pytorch

Does anyone have experience working with SentenceTransformer (Bert)?

**My Code:**

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('roberta-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
```

**My Error:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ga2943/.cache\\torch\\sentence_transformers\\public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de_reimers_sentence-transformers_v0.2_roberta-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens.zip\\modules.json'
```

Once in a while I get a different error running the same Code with another Bert-model:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird: 'C:\\Users\\ga2943/.cache\\torch\\sentence_transformers\\public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de_reimers_sentence-transformers_v0.2_bert-large-nli-cls-token.zip\\model.zip'
```

(Translates to: Data is beeing used in a different Process at the time, which cant be the case. I restarted my machine to ensure all programs are closed in the background but no difference)

The first time I ran my code it worked. It downloaded the Sentenceencoder I wanted (different Bert model)  Now that I want to test a different model, it does not download it but gives me the errors.

Funny thing is, on a different Computer I was able to load a different model but it resulted in the same case. Only the first ever downloaded model works on the machine.

Any ideas? Still getting the error, no one knows how to fix it?

Comment: How are you running the code? I mean whether the python process was stopped after first run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to **re-install everything** over again to solve the issue. I cant put my finger on what caused the error. As I did not delete or update anything myself I am assuming anaconda patched something without letting me know.

The second error still remains and occurs unpredictable from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I found exact same error.

The way i solved this.
step 1: `'C:\\Users\\ga2943/.cache\\torch\\sentence_transformers\\public.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de_reimers_sentence-transformers_v0.2_roberta-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens.zip\\modules.json'`

if you are using "`linux`" then delete `/root/.cache/sentcetransformer`

step 2: `restart` the container or program.

there is also another way that you can `Download` the specific model and use `path` in code.

Answer (score -1):

if you have internet you can work with the models easily, else you need to download the model and specify the path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).